# Autoformat in VS Code on semicolon, enter, etc

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting

Is there a way to make VS Code work with autoformat like other VS versions ?
Mostly I want it to autoformat the line/block when I close it( so with ; } ).

Also I would like to autotab in advance when I make empty lines or similar empty blocks while the default behaviour is to just stay at starting tab.

I program mainly in C#.

Comment: There is a setting `editor format on type` you could set to true and see if it helps.  And `auto indent` to true.

Comment: I already have that active, but apparently it doesn't always work.